# Registering routes with Laravel but make them unaccessible

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make a single page CRUD application with Laravel. I will use ajax to create, edit and delete my entity, and also to render partial views. The corresponding controller methods will process the information and return the views.

I want to register the routes so I can call the different methods when necessary. I don't see any other way:

[image]

However, registering them so I can do something like this `{{ Form::open(['route' => ['cities.store', $city->id]]) }}` will allow access via the URL, and I only want to make those routes accessible through the tools I am going to create in that one page CRUD.

I can only think of applying a before filter, but what would be the filter? Also, any other ideas on how I should approach this situtation?

Comment: I do not get the question at all. What is the problem? What tools? Also, I cannot see the route `cities.new`.

Comment: "I only want to make those routes accessible through the tools I am going to create in that one page CRUD." sounds like you want a [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](http://laravel.com/docs/html#csrf-protection) with a `before => 'csrf'` filter. Then you just force yourself not to use the route from other pages.

Comment: @delmadord tools meaning the forms and buttons there will be in that single page, but that's it. I don't want to enable access from anywhere (like directly with an URL) but using that single page and its CRUD "tools".

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do something similar with a web service I created. Basically, I wanted only my app to be able to access the routes I created.

What I ended up doing was adding a hashed key to each request being sent, then checking for this key value in the controller. So, only if the key is present and matches the one sent would you then process the request.

Or, if you're using forms, you could do something like the following:

```
  //check if request was sent from our form
    if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
        return Response::json( array(
            'msg' => 'Unauthorized access attempt'
        ) );
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

another way that doesnt need tokens but is less secure, you got to know what you need,
is using laravels request information

```
if (Request::ajax())
{
//your action
}else{
//error
}
```

note this only works when your application always uses ajax you could even type this in your before filter and add it to all needed routes